# Turn off iPhone 5 (4 inch) display support?

Tags: ios, app-store, bundle, splash-screen, iphone-5

I did handle this situation by simply not provide Default-568h@2x.png along my bundle.
But Apple rejected my app for not to support iPhone 5.

**How did others get over this?**
Is there some Info.plist key I can set, or something?

---

If I provide a Default-568h@2x.png, my window, my controller views are resized to 568, though, I have every view set to 480 in IB.

Comment: No Apple requires you to support 4" devices.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you actually want people to use your app?

Comment: @Marko: People do use it every day. This is just an update.

Answer (score 1):

"On Thursday, Apple informed iOS App developers that as of May 1, the App Store will stop accepting new apps or app updates that access a device's unique identifier or fail to support Retina devices and the iPhone 5."  on Mar 21, 2013

so you can not upload any app that won't support iPhone 5 screen size

[you can read it here](http://www.macworld.com/article/2031573/apple-sets-may-1-deadline-for-udid-iphone-5-app-changes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Simply do not turn off.
Apple just approved this workaround on the other day.

If you have no intention to redesign the UI dimensions, wrap every view into a 480px height wrapper (or two if you have bad assumptions with frame values, like I had :D).